# How to build knob like spinner in iOS sdk?

Tags: iphone

I want to build a spinner for menu selection like the one in where to? IPhone app as shown in image below. Any hints?

[image]

Comment: screenshots for this kind of question are very helpful, since not everyone has/is willing to look at, random specific apps on the app store.

Comment: I am sorry, just added a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't need to be very hard. The easiest is probably a UIImageView with the image of the actual spinner, and another UIImageView with the yellow selection highlight (a transparent PNG) overlaying. The rotation can then be controlled with the transform property of the first UIImageView.

This should of course be nicely encapsulated in a custom UIView subclass.